# Python Searching for files and Importing them

Tags: python, import

I need to write a function that walks through directories searching for files that end in _prj.py, and then extract some lists from there. The way I'm doing it right now is by using `os.path.walk` and then importing. My code looks like this:

```
for py_file in files:
    if py_file.endswith("_prj.py"):
        print py_file[:-3]
        module = py_file[:-3]
        import module
```

However, I get an import error:

```
ImportError: No module named module
```

I think I understand why, I'm just not sure how I would make the import statement work. Is there a way to make the module variable be read as the file name instead of "module"?

Comment: [`__import__(module_name)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__), although you're probably doing the wrong thing. See also [importlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html).

Comment: You are trying some thing similar to `import "math"` and this would surely return error.

Comment: As in I shouldn't be importing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of import a module by a String name is by using another module known as `importlib`

```
import importlib

math_module = importlib.import_module("math")

print math_module.sqrt(25)
>>> 5.0
```

Comment: If I use importlib, does the module have to be in the same directory? If it does have to be, does the fact that I'm using `os.path.walk` to get to the directory the modules are in solve this?

Comment: it would work the same way as `import` statement works, if you could import the python file using `import` statement then probably you could import it using importlib.